# React Native deep linking from other app

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

There is the our application which should be available on company://upload. I created the itent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="company"
    android:host="upload" />
</intent-filter>
```

It is opening the application, but inside the react-native I couldn't catch the url. My implementation:

```
componentWillMount() {
  Linking
    .getInitialURL()
    .then(event => this.handleOpenURL(event))
    .catch(console.error);
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  this.props.loadCredentials();
}

handleOpenURL(event) {
  console.log(event);
  switch (event.url) {
    case `${Config.APP_SCHEMA}upload`:
      Actions.Upload();
      break;
    default:
      Actions.Home();
  }
}
```

- The implementation is in the `router.js` and this is the first React component.
- The intent-filter is in the .MainActivity
- When I click on the application on the other application it is opening it up, so the java part of the linking is working.

Versions:

- `"react-native": "0.42.0",`
- `Android SDK 23`

Comment: Where did you add the javascript part inside the first react component? If so, move it to the router.

Comment: I'm using `react-native-flux-router`. It is on an above level. But, the `Linking` package should catch it everywhere else I think, isn't it?

Comment: I do not think so. It will definitely work if you add it inside the router though.

Comment: What do you mean inside the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a script for testing the deep-linking:

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "company://$1" com.companyapps/.MainActivity`

The deep-linking is right, the problem was with the Java part of my application.